# add dynamic reactive form groups in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, typescript

I have a message service that has a reply function. This reply function is specific to the group of messages a user wants to reply to. I need to dynamically add form validation in typescript and the template, with some sort of loop around the form builder inside the constructor, then how do i pass the mailData.length value back to the constructor? 
 i have tried the angular tutorials and some others online, but no luck.

```
// mail.component.ts 
  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.MailForm = fb.group({
      "content": [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, /*other validation*/])]
    });
  }
  sendMail(mail:any) {
  // Send mail
  }
```

then in mail.html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of mailData; let i = index">
    // display original messages here

    // reply section 
    <div id="{{i}}">
        <form [formGroup]="i.MailForm">
            <textarea class="mailContainerTextArea" 
            [formControl]="i.MailForm.controls['content']">
            </textarea>
            <!-- Reply button -->
            <button class="mailReply" (click)="sendMail(i.MailForm.value)" [disabled]="!MailForm.valid">Send</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching and playing around i finllay got it, the tutorials online only cater of added elements on an event like a click, not form groups created based on existing array data. The answer is based on parts from [Scotch-io-nestedForms](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2)

```
    //component 
    import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
    //other imports FormArray is the important one 

export class SomeComponent{
    public MailFormArray:FormGroup;
    cnstructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.MailFormArray = fb.group({
            "reply": fb.array([
                this.createForms(),
            ])
        });
      }
      // generate the array content
      createForms() {
            return this.fb.group({
              "content": [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-z]')])]
            });
      }
      // create dynamic fields by calling this function after json data loaded, and pass in the json data length 
      addForms(jsonLength) {
          for(let i = 0; i < jsonLength; i++){
            const control = <FormArray>this.MailFormArray.controls['reply'];
            control.push(this.createForms());
          }
      }
     // replyForm
     replyForm(theReply) {
       console.log(JSON.stringify(theReply));
     }
}
```

Then in the Template

```
<form [formGroup]="MailFormArray">
    <div formArrayName="reply">
        <div *ngFor="let key of jsonData; let j = index;">
            <div [formGroupName]="j">
                <div *ngFor="let item of key;">
                    <textarea  maxlength="255" formControlName="content"></textarea>
                    <button (click)="replyForm(MailFormArray.controls.reply.controls[j].value)">Send</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```